# How to get a X line from file1 and Y line from file2 using shell command?

Tags: shell, awk, scripting, grep

In file 1,
'Server restoration is complete now. It will be operational within few seconds. Please keep all the log file once the restoration is complete.'

In file 2,
'Restoration was successfully terminated due to .SA file mismatch. Please keep the log file for your future reference.'

Now I want to get both the complete lines from my file 1 and file 2. How can I print or get these lines at a time?

Comment: if you only want both files , `cat file1 file2` but it's very ugly...

Comment: yes.... from those files I just want to extract those two lines. @demonking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope i understand it right.

```
cat file1 file2 | grep -E '(^Restoration\ was\ successfully|^Server\ restoration\ is\ complete)'
```

When the files start with single-quotes :

```
cat file1 file2 | grep -E '(^\'Restoration\ was\ successfully|^\'Server\ restoration\ is\ complete)'
```

Comment: UUOC: You can avoid cat with `grep -hE '(...)' file1 file2`

Comment: Yes.... its working now.... :-) @demonking